# How to get cell's property in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I put a Image on my report, and I am using a reference assembly to create the image, I set the Image's content with an expression like this:

```
=Code.GetImage(200,200)
```

[image]

I want to pass the Image cell's with and height to function **GetImage**, not hard coded like 200X200. I know I can read its with and height from report designer's property form, but that is not what I want to do.

Is there a way to get the Image cell's width and height properties inside the expresiion?

Answer (score 0):

I want to be able to do this too, but my instinct is that this is not possible unfortunately. The way to refer to Objects in the report is using the ReportItems collection. One would assume that something like ReportItems!Image2.Width would be what you need, but this does not work. Additionally, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx) declares that:

> Items within the ReportItems collection have only one property: Value.

which scuppers that whole theory.